# django // conditional settings depend on aws instance server

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

## Environment

django 2.2

python 3.6

AWS EC2 ubuntu instance

gunicorn

nginx

---

## My setting

Now I'm using one production server aws ubuntu instance.

I separated `settings.py` depond on local and production server as follows.

```py
# local : Project/setting/dev.py
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
database = {
    ..skip..
}


# production : Project/setting/real.py
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['~real_server_host of ec2~']
database = {
    ..AWS RDS instance for real..
}


# manage.py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.dev")

# wsgi.py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.real")
```

---

## Question

I have to operate **one more aws instance for test** before deploy to real.

So I made same EC2 instance and RDS instance(dumped from real rds) for test.

But I don't have any nice idea how to seperate `os.environ.setdefault` in `wsgi.py`

Once I made one more settings file for test server.

```py
# Project/setting/test.py
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['~test_server_host of ec2~']
database = {
    ..AWS RDS instance for test..
}
```

I expect the code below to work.

```py
# wsgi.py
if realserver:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.real")
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.test")
```

and I have to use another api url depend on real or test.

```py
# views.py
if real:
   get_data = requests.get(real_api.apiurl.com)
else :
   get_data = requests.get(test_api.apiurl.com)
```

How do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully solved the problem, so I share the solution.

I put environment variables of the same key and different value for each server and use 'settings' for 'TEST' when the environment variable is 'test'.

```py
# wsgi.py

try:
    test = os.environ['IS_ENV']
    if test == 'test':
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.prod_test")
    else:
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.prod_eb")
except KeyError:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project.settings.prod_eb")
```